# Ladder diagram in winSPS

Tags: rgb, plc, codesys

I have to express an RGB led in a ladder diagram using winSPS. I have used CodeSys before but that is all my experience. Can someone help me with the schematic for it?

Comment: Are you asking for the ladder diagram to program it or the schematic for wiring the hardware.  If you are asking about the programming, what colors are you trying to display?

Comment: i would like to display them one by one separately

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about electronic circuit design, not programming.

Answer (score -1):

You are going to need 3 PWM outputs on your plc. One output to Red, one to Green, and one to Blue.  Depending on what exact color you want you would send a PWM signal to each color.  For example, if you just wanted Red you would send a full PWM signal (high signal)  to the red led.  If you wanted a orange-ish color you would send a lower pulse width for red and for blue.  You can even get a white color if you send full pulse width to red, green and blue.

This arduino tutorial does a pretty good job of illustrating what is required.
[rdb led tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-3-rgb-leds/breadboard-layout)

Comment: That i knew already. I am not sure how to make the connection using the ladder diagram components